# Is a pure type the same as an immutable type?

Tags: c#, .net

I was checking out the documentation of `PureAttribute` in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and I was surprised that it can be applied at class level. I knew what a pure function is, but I had never seen it applied to a type. In the MSDN documentation it states the following:

> Indicates that a **type** or method is pure, that is, it does not make any visible state changes.

(bolded for highlighting purposes)

So my question is, if a pure type does not make any visible state changes, is that the same as an immutable type? Are both terms, if applied at the type level, equivalent? If not, can someone show me an example of a pure type that is not immutable or viceversa.

Comment: I'll leave the answer to someone who knows for sure, but I suspect it is slightly stricter than an immutable type, in that it must not cause any visible state changes *anywhere* (not just to its own state).  In theory, a type could be immutable, but still produce external side effects.  That would suggest that pure types are a subset of immutable types.

Comment: Yes I think this is what they meant - but as @MikeStrobel said: it is more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional - I am thinking of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science) - normaly you exclude thinks like writing to the console and quering from a database (or from the system clock) as well - and this is not included in immutability in the MSDN sense

Comment: And of course this is not enforced in any way - so it's more or less useless right now

Comment: @MikeStrobel I think you are probably right. Duh, how did I miss that? :p

Comment: It is just a shortcut for a class whose methods are all pure.  That doesn't happen very often, I see just two classes in the .NET Framework for example.  Static classes with no fields.

Answer (score 2):

No, those are not the same:

- An immutable type could have methods that mutate another object and this would not be pure.
- On the other hand a type could expose mutable fields and yet only have pure methods that do not modify those fields.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your posts.

Comment: I am sceptical for the second one. An instance of pure type should not cause any side-effects, no matter it is by its methods or by exposing mutable fields.

Comment: The type might not be pure, but it may contain only pure methods (perhaps by chance, if not explicitly by design).